# Using methods inside a constructor

Tags: java, oop, methods, constructor

I'm new to learning Java and was trying to understand OOP, but I can't seem to find anyone who has the same exact question. My question is, is it okay to use methods inside a constructor like the example here:

```
package ezrab.nl;

public class Calculations {

    private int number;
    private int multiplier;

    private String operator = "";

    public Calculations(int number, String operator, int multiplier) {
        this.number = number;
        this.operator = operator;
        this.multiplier = multiplier;
        switch (getOperator()) {
        case "+":
            System.out.println(getNumber() + getMultiplier());
            break;
        case "-":
            System.out.println(getNumber() - getMultiplier());
            break;
        case "*":
            System.out.println(getNumber() * getMultiplier());
            break;
        case "/":
            System.out.println(getNumber() / getMultiplier());
            break;
        case "%":
            System.out.println(getNumber() % getMultiplier());
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Something went wrong.");
        }
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return this.number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public int getMultiplier() {
        return this.multiplier;
    }

    public void setMultiplier(int multiplier) {
        this.multiplier = multiplier;
    }

    public String getOperator() {
        return this.operator;
    }

    public void setOperator(String operator) {
        this.operator = operator;
    }

}
```

So I'd like to know, is it allowed to use the methods I've created inside the constructor.

**EDIT:** I'd like to point out that the program is working. I just want to know if I followed the rules to OOP correctly.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: nope, not really, *unless* you have to. One thing here, is that methods used inside a constructor *must* not be polymorphic, make these `final`

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what you have done, your code should compile and run at least.  More typically, in production, you might see something doing logging statements, instead of making calls to `System.out`.

Comment: @Eugene I don't think he actually needs to call these methods, since they're just getters and the values are already available as parameters to the constructor.  So, the only issue then, would be if `println` is final/static.

Comment: Imho, I advise you to create a separate method ```print```. Because constructor must only create and initialize the object. And not to print or do something. For each action create a method.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen of course he doesn't, but than he *does* call them; in such a case...

Comment: It's not recommended practice though, because somebody who inherits from your class can unintentionally break it. As a general rule, any method called from the constructor should be either final or private. @Ezrab_

Comment: Your question was "I just want to know if I followed the rules to OOP correctly." My answer would be "No". Since you've called methods related to the object that is not constructed yet (until the constructor ends).

Comment: @SanjaySs Okay so I'd make it `final` so that it wouldn't be able to change right?

Comment: Are there even any "rules to OOP"? If it compiles and does the job, what rule's broken. (I know that the class snippet doesn't fully do it's supposed job).

Comment: Speaking of style: calling the second number ```multiplier``` regardless of operation is not very pleasing to the eye. You may want to use some neutral naming, like ```number1```, ```number2```.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put behavior of object separately with creation:

```
public class Calculations {

private int number;
private int multiplier;
private String operator = "";

public Calculations(int number, String operator, int multiplier) {
    this.number = number;
    this.operator = operator;
    this.multiplier = multiplier;
}

public int getNumber() {
    return this.number;
}

public void setNumber(int number) {
    this.number = number;
}

public int getMultiplier() {
    return this.multiplier;
}

public void setMultiplier(int multiplier) {
    this.multiplier = multiplier;
}

public String getOperator() {
    return this.operator;
}

public void setOperator(String operator) {
    this.operator = operator;
}

public void print() {
     switch (getOperator()) {
    case "+":
        System.out.println(getNumber() + getMultiplier());
        break;
    case "-":
        System.out.println(getNumber() - getMultiplier());
        break;
    case "*":
        System.out.println(getNumber() * getMultiplier());
        break;
    case "/":
        System.out.println(getNumber() / getMultiplier());
        break;
    case "%":
        System.out.println(getNumber() % getMultiplier());
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Something went wrong.");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> is it allowed to use the methods I've created inside the constructor.

It's allowed but dangerous as you need to know if everything which should be set, has been set. It's better to use the value which was passed as a parameter.

However your `switch` should be in the constructor as you can change the operator or operand later. I would have a separate method for it.

NOTE: Having a field called `multiplier` is confusing as it's not a multiplier in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's allowed but better way is to separate the behavior and construction of object. Constructors are mainly used to set properties of the class.

Answer (score 0):

To better code in OOP (Object Oriented Programming) this concept you are referring to is known as Encapsulation. You can generally code in the way you are saying to do it. However, down the line when the application gets bigger, it would make your life much easier if you follow established design patterns. Please review this link for the Encapsulation concept:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm